# Deserialization JSON data

Tags: c#, json

I'm having trouble deserializing json data, I have this code which I'm using successfully with other json data:

```
        string url = string.Format("http://farmsense-prod.apigee.net/v1/moonphases/?d=1494981184");
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Lunar_data.RootObject));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data_moon = (Lunar_data.RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return data_moon;
```

this code will return only null values!

Here is my class which generated with **https://jsonutils.com**/

```
public class Lunar_data
{

    public class RootObject
    {

        [JsonProperty("Error")]
        public int Error { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ErrorMsg")]
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TargetDate")]
        public string TargetDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Moon")]
        public IList<string> Moon { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Index")]
        public int Index { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Age")]
        public double Age { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Phase")]
        public string Phase { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Distance")]
        public double Distance { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Illumination")]
        public double Illumination { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AngularDiameter")]
        public double AngularDiameter { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DistanceToSun")]
        public double DistanceToSun { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SunAngularDiameter")]
        public double SunAngularDiameter { get; set; }
    }

}
```

and this is my json data which is really simple and yet I can't get it right:

```
[{"Error":0,"ErrorMsg":"success","TargetDate":"1350526582","Moon":["Hunter's\/Harvest Moon"],"Index":2,"Age":2.9555953469264,"Phase":"Waxing Crescent","Distance":363325.22,"Illumination":0.1,"AngularDiameter":0.54815395361483,"DistanceToSun":149016616.79983,"SunAngularDiameter":0.53520976935835}]
```

Finally after some search I found some people using **Newtonsoft.Json** but I couldn't use it because of those quotes in json data, please any help?

Comment: Did you try to use Newtonsoft.Json and failed ?

Comment: I couldn't use it, I need somehow to deal with those quotes in json data!

Comment: @khalefa, claiming that Newtonsoft.Json cannot handle those quotes is like saying that Newtonsoft.Json cannot handle Json at all. Who knew... ;-)

Comment: I said I could not handle them and @Nemanja  understand me and gave the right answer, thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your json is an array and you're deserializing into an instance of RootObject. I tried

```
const string jsondata = "[{\"Error\":0,\"ErrorMsg\":\"success\",\"TargetDate\":\"1350526582\",\"Moon\":[\"Hunter's\\/Harvest Moon\"],\"Index\":2,\"Age\":2.9555953469264,\"Phase\":\"Waxing Crescent\",\"Distance\":363325.22,\"Illumination\":0.1,\"AngularDiameter\":0.54815395361483,\"DistanceToSun\":149016616.79983,\"SunAngularDiameter\":0.53520976935835}]";

Lunar_data.RootObject[] res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lunar_data.RootObject[]>(jsondata);
```

and it worked fine. I had to escape the quotes because the json is in a string const in my code, but you don't need to (assuming the response you get back from the http call is properly formatted).

Alternatively, in your code, just replace

```
Lunar_data.RootObject
```

with

```
Lunar_data.RootObject[]
```

so you get

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Lunar_data.RootObject[]));
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
var data_moon = (Lunar_data.RootObject[])serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

and it works. But I would use Newtonsoft.

Comment: It works!, Thank you so much Nemanja  you just saved my project!